# Align images list to fit window's width

Tags: image, list, window, alignment

I have a list of about 40 images in different sizes.

I'm trying to order them in a `table` that have the following characteristics:

1. The table always fit window size.
2. All table lines height are equal.

like you can see in this page: http://www.lihihod.com/brides/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found the solution.
It's called "Justified Image Gallery".

Amazing Jquery plug